# How do you add a form to a content type?

Tags: views, webforms

I have a view that had a list of equipment.  Each equipment node in the view needs a form so I can upload equipment drawings.  I would like the form to belong to the node because it makes it easier for submission to understand it's context.  Is there any way to do this?

I have webforms installed and I can create a webform for each node individually, but for some reason I can't find a way to add a webform for the content type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with custom code.

- The form does not need to be inline to Content Type.
- Consider this example
- You have custom form. form builder of which takes an argument as nid.

  function custom_form_builder($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
     $form['nid'] = array(
       '#type' => 'hidden',
       '#value' => $nid, 
     );
    // form field goes here.
  }
- Now in your view add nid field along with other fields you need and an extra custom field.
- In your views you can define custom template for custom field.
- Implement [template_preprocess_views_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7) to call drupal_get_form('form_id',$nid) and make it available on the custom template.
- Print the form on the template.
- Now when the custom form gets submit you can get the nid to update in $form_state['values']['nid'].

Answer (score 0):

Each webform is a node, so you can use a **node reference** field on your equipment nodes and render that within your View.